# Getting "Undefined offset: 2 error ( the error is in: 'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,)

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code below in a view for the user introduce some data to register for a conference. Then I have the RegistrationController storeRegistratioInfo(). When the user fills the form and submits the form is made an ajax request and it appears an error:

> {message: "Undefined offset: 2", exception: "ErrorException",…}
>       exception:"ErrorException" file : RegistrationController.php" line :194 message : "Undefined offset: 2" trace: [,…]

The line 194 is this:

```
'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
```

The full storeRegistration() method is below.

Code in the view:

```
@foreach($selectedRtypes as $k => $selectedRtype)
    @foreach(range(1,$selectedRtype['quantity']) as $val)

        @if($allParticipants == 1)
            <h6 class="text-heading-blue mb-3 pb-2 font-weight-bold">
                Participant - {{$val}} - {{$k}}</h6>

            <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                <label for="name{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}"
                       class="text-gray">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}"
                       name="participant_name[]" required
                       class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                <label for="surname{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}"
                       class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" id="surname{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}"
                       required class="form-control"
                       name="participant_surname[]" value="">
            </div>
            @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                    @if($customQuestion->hasOptions())
                        {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                            $customQuestion->name,
                            $customQuestion->options,
                            ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                            'form-control',
                            $customQuestion->type)
                        !!}
                    @endif
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="participant_question_required[]"
                           value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
                           name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <input type="hidden" value="foo"
                   name="participant_name[]"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="bar"
                   name="participant_surname[]"/>
        @endif
        <input type="hidden" name="rtypes[]"
               value="{{ $selectedRtype['id'] }}"/>
    @endforeach
    @if ($allParticipants == 0)
        @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                @if($customQuestion->hasOptions())
                    {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                        $customQuestion->name,
                        $customQuestion->options,
                        ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                        'form-control',
                        $customQuestion->type)
                    !!}
                @endif
                <input type="hidden"
                       name="participant_question_required[]"
                       value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                <input type="hidden"
                       value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
                       name="participant_question_id[]"/>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

storeRegistration():

```
public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
        $allParticipants = Conference::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;
        $user = Auth::user();

        $rules = [];
        $messages = [];

        if (isset($request->participant_question_required)) {
            $messages = [
                'participant_question.*.required' => 'Fill all mandatory fields.',
                'participant_name.*.required' => 'Fill the field name.',
                'participant_surname.*.required' => 'Fill the field surname.',
            ];

            foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
                $rule = 'string|max:255'; // I think string should come before max
                // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
                if ($value) {
                    $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
                }

                // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
                $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
            }
        }

        if ($allParticipants) {

            $rules["participant_name.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
            $rules["participant_surname.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';

        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors = json_decode($errors);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $errors
            ], 422);
        }

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $registration = Registration::create([
                'conference_id' => $id,
                'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',
            ]);

            $participants = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++) {
                $name = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_name[$i] : '';
                $surname = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_surname[$i] : '';
                $participants[] = Participant::create([
                    'name' => $name,
                    'surname' => $surname,
                    'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                    'registration_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

                ]);
            }
            if (isset($request->participant_question))
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
                    $answer = Answer::create([
                        'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
                        'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                        'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                    ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);
    }
```

If there is a custom question, for example, "Receive Notifications" the generated html is like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Receive Notifications?</label>                                      
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="Yes" class="form-check-input" 1=""> 
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Yes</label></div> 
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="No" class="form-check-input" 1="">    
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">No</label></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]">
</div>
```

The  "dd($request->participant_question)" in storeRegistration() shows if for the first partipant is selected "Yes" and for the second participant "no" shows:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "Yes"
  1 => "No"
]
```

The `dd($participant)` in:

```
if (isset($request->participant_question)) {
          for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++) {
               dd($participants);
               ...
```

Shows:

```
array:2 [
  0 => Participant {#287
    #fillable: array:4 [
      0 => "name"
      1 => "surname"
      2 => "registration_id"
      3 => "registration_type_id"
    ]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: true
    #attributes: array:7 [
      "name" => "John"
      "surname" => "Keane"
      "registration_id" => 24
      "registration_type_id" => "1"
      "updated_at" => "2018-06-03 13:07:18"
      "created_at" => "2018-06-03 13:07:18"
      "id" => 47
    ]
    #original: array:7 [
      "name" => "John"
      "surname" => "Keane"
      "registration_id" => 24
      "registration_type_id" => "1"
      "updated_at" => "2018-06-03 13:07:18"
      "created_at" => "2018-06-03 13:07:18"
      "id" => 47
    ]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [
      0 => "*"
    ]
  }
  1 => Participant {#289
    #fillable: array:4 [
      0 => "name"
      1 => "surname"
      2 => "registration_id"
      3 => "registration_type_id"
    ]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: true
    #attributes: array:7 [
      "name" => "Jake"
      "surname" => "L"
      "registration_id" => 24
      "registration_type_id" => "1"
      "updated_at" => "2018-06-03 13:07:18"
      "created_at" => "2018-06-03 13:07:18"
      "id" => 48
    ]
    #original: array:7 [
      "name" => "Jake"
      "surname" => "L"
      "registration_id" => 24
      "registration_type_id" => "1"
      "updated_at" => "2018-06-03 13:07:18"
      "created_at" => "2018-06-03 13:07:18"
      "id" => 48
    ]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [
      0 => "*"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes it's with Larave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through an array of questions that may or may not be connected to the array of participants.  The questions array comes from the $request returning from POST:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="No" class="form-check-input" 1="">    
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]">
```

and so forth.

BUT, you are making an array of participants (and creating their ids) *independent* of the amount of questions.  IE you might have 11 questions that make this loop here:

```
 @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
```

And thus, when you loop on the creation side:

```
 for($i=0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
```

$i might === 10.  However, you may only have 2 new participants made from the form.  This would mean that your `$participants[]` would only consist of `$participants[0]` and `$participants[1]`.  So when looping inside the question array (which has a count of 11), your participants array is going to fail when it gets past index 1 (it will fail when `$i === 2` making a `$participants[2]` call) since there are only 2 total in the array.

To fix this, you have to remove the

```
'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
```

from the creation array.  Again, the count of participants is not related to the number of questions, so this will fail.  You need to link the new participant to the question directly.  Possibly when you create the participant, THEN check to see which question he answered when looping through the participant_name loop.  You can't really do this with your existing code - you are trying to link two things that are not linked on the form.  I think you will need to change either the linkage on the form, or have a way to combine the new participant to the question he specifically answered.  But that's beyond the scope of this question - the reason it doesn't work is that you have two different arrays with two different counts.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, its pretty obvious that the "participants" array does not have values beyond the $i pointer prescribed within your FOR loop statement. I also noticed, you didn't close your IF and FOR statements properly. You might want to check that as well.

```
if(isset($request->participant_question))
    for($i=0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
        $answer = Answer::create([
            'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
            'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
            'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
        ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the same issue, closing the if and for properly in the storeRegistration().

Comment: The     "dd($request->participant_question);"
shows the question id an the value that the user introduced for the question "  array:2 [
  0 => "test"
  1 => "no"
]".